# Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line

Tags: asp.net

What is wrong with this line:

```
<asp:HyperLink  ID="linkViewAlbum" NavigateUrl="~/Photos/ViewAlbum.aspx" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#_webContext.RootUrl %>files/photos/<%#((Folder)Container.DataItem).FullPathToCoverImage %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

It gives me an error mentioned in the title.
It was working when I put this which is exactly same as above but in a img src:

```
<img src="<%#_webContext.RootUrl %>files/photos/<%#((Folder)Container.DataItem).FullPathToCoverImage %>"  />
```

Please help I am really struggling with this...Is there a good link to explain about these directives...cannot seem to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Switch ImageUrl to the follwoing:

```
ImageUrl='<%#_webContext.RootUrl + "files/photos/" + ((Folder)Container.DataItem).FullPathToCoverImage %>'
```

`<%# Eval() %>` is a databinding expression and must evaluate to the property. You can't concatenate it with another string outside of the `Eval` expression.

In other words, with ASP.NET controls, you can only use 1 `Eval` per property. If you need to concatenate them, then do it inside the single `Eval`.